# I need a way to add a non-button title using tkinter in python

Tags: python, text, tkinter

My code so far is this:

```
import tkinter

def hello():
    a = tkinter.Button(text ="what is this", padx = 10, pady = 10)
    a.pack()
    c = tkinter.Button(text ="what do you want", padx = 10, pady = 10)
    c.pack()

b = tkinter.Button(text = "Welcome to the interface. click to get started", command = hello, padx = 10, pady = 10)
b.pack()
```

I want to click the first button and have it display the next button with a bit of text above it. I tried print as a last resort,  but it goes in the shell, as i thought it would. nothing seems to work. i have seen some things about a 'text_widget' but i have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: On each click, do you want to add new line above or just a single line of text, changing depending on clicked button?

Comment: So a `Label` instead of a button?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is `Label`. Label is a way to present text onto a tk window. For example, you are using `c = tkinter.Button(text ="what do you want", padx = 10, pady = 10)`. To create it as text, you should use `c = tkinter.Label(text ="what do you want", padx = 10, pady = 10)`.

Also, this question provided little information about what you wanted to do, so it is hard to show what you've asked for.

If what you wanted was to have a button with text above it, you should use:

```
examplelabel = tkinter.Label(text = "Example Text")
examplelabel.pack()
examplebutton = tkinter.Button(...)
examplebutton.pack()
```

Sorry if this answer was poor, I'm not so good with this type of python.